# Functional Javascript map/reduce in preparing report data

Tags: javascript, report

I am struggling to understand how to properly employ [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to assemble summary/report data (i.e., grouped counts). I typically do this manually by looping over the data with `forEach` and building up the object, but I feel like chaining map and reduce has got to be a more elegant, functional way of doing it; I'm just failing to figure out how to do this correctly.

Here is where my experimentation has gotten me:

```
const articleData = [
    {newsSource: "AP", title: "Some article.", category: "World"},
    {newsSource: "BBC", title: "Some article.", category: "Politics"},
    {newsSource: "CBS", title: "Some article.", category: "Sports"},
    {newsSource: "CNN", title: "Some article.", category: "Finance"},
    {newsSource: "CNN", title: "Another article.", category: "Politics"},
    {newsSource: "NBC", title: "Some article.", category: "Politics"},
    {newsSource: "NBC", title: "Another article.", category: "Finance"},
    {newsSource: "Reuters", title: "Some article.", category: "World"},
    {newsSource: "Reuters", title: "Another article.", category: "Politics"},
    {newsSource: "Reuters", title: "Yet another article.", category: "Finance"}
];

// I want to set reportData to be the result of the chained map/reduce
// ...not declare it here and assemble it within the functions below
let reportData = {};

articleData.map((item, index) => {
    if (item.newsSource) return item.newsSource;
})
.reduce((acc, newsSource) => {

    if (!reportData[newsSource]) {
        reportData[newsSource] = 1;
    } else {
        reportData[newsSource] = reportData[newsSource] + 1;
    }

    return (acc, reportData);

});

console.log(reportData);
// Expected output:
// { AP: 1, BBC: 1, CBS: 1, CNN: 2, NBC: 2, Reuters: 3 }
```

There are a number of problems here. (Not the least of which is that it skips the first data element! *I think* I understand why, but I don't know how to fix it.) But most importantly, I want to understand how to construct my `reduce` function so I'm not altering `reportData` within it, rather I'm returning the properly structured data shown under "Expected output".

Reducing a flat array is clear to me, but I get confused once I'm dealing with a structure of any depth beyond that.

Comment: You need to pass an initial value, otherwise the first element of the array will be taken as the initial value and not iterated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) directly on `articleData`:

```
reportData = articleData.reduce(function(c, a) {
  c[a.newsSource] = (c[a.newsSource] || 0) + 1;
  return c;
}, {});

console.log(reportData);
```

Note that as @CertainPerformance pointed out in their comment, you need to pass an initial value to `reduce` otherwise the first value in the array is used as the initial value and not included in the iteration.

```js
const articleData = [{
    newsSource: "AP",
    title: "Some article.",
    category: "World"
  },
  {
    newsSource: "BBC",
    title: "Some article.",
    category: "Politics"
  },
  {
    newsSource: "CBS",
    title: "Some article.",
    category: "Sports"
  },
  {
    newsSource: "CNN",
    title: "Some article.",
    category: "Finance"
  },
  {
    newsSource: "CNN",
    title: "Another article.",
    category: "Politics"
  },
  {
    newsSource: "NBC",
    title: "Some article.",
    category: "Politics"
  },
  {
    newsSource: "NBC",
    title: "Another article.",
    category: "Finance"
  },
  {
    newsSource: "Reuters",
    title: "Some article.",
    category: "World"
  },
  {
    newsSource: "Reuters",
    title: "Another article.",
    category: "Politics"
  },
  {
    newsSource: "Reuters",
    title: "Yet another article.",
    category: "Finance"
  }
];

reportData = articleData.reduce(function(c, a) {
  c[a.newsSource] = (c[a.newsSource] || 0) + 1;
  return c;
}, {});

console.log(reportData);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass fist value to accumulate in `2nd param` of `reduce` method. You can skip value or `manipulate` the value in `callback` function.

```js
const articleData = [
  { newsSource: "AP", title: "Some article.", category: "World" },
  { newsSource: "BBC", title: "Some article.", category: "Politics" },
  { newsSource: "CBS", title: "Some article.", category: "Sports" },
  { newsSource: "CNN", title: "Some article.", category: "Finance" },
  { newsSource: "CNN", title: "Another article.", category: "Politics" },
  { newsSource: "NBC", title: "Some article.", category: "Politics" },
  { newsSource: "NBC", title: "Another article.", category: "Finance" },
  { newsSource: "Reuters", title: "Some article.", category: "World" },
  { newsSource: "Reuters", title: "Another article.", category: "Politics" },
  { newsSource: "Reuters", title: "Yet another article.", category: "Finance" }
];

const reportData = articleData.reduce((acc, { newsSource }) => {
  if (!acc[newsSource]) acc[newsSource] = 0;
  acc[newsSource] += 1;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(reportData);
```